# ASP.NET Core Web API Error - How to resolve More than one DbContext was found. Specify which one to use in update-database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I have two DBContexts:

1. ApplicationIdentityDbContext
2. MyAppDbContext

For add-migration, I used these two in the **PM**:

1. add-migration InitialIdentity -OutputDir "Infrastructure/Identity/Migrations" -context ApplicationIdentityDbContext
2. add-migration InitialDDM -OutputDir "Persistence/Migrations" -context MyAppDbContext

The two add-migration works.

However, for the update-database when I did:

> update-database -verbose

I got this error:

> More than one DbContext was found. Specify which one to use. Use the '-Context' parameter for PowerShell commands and the '--context' parameter for dotnet commands

How do I resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: SUGGESTION: `Update-Database -context MyAppDbContext -v`.  I always 1) explicitly specify the context ... in *ALL* my EF CLI commands, 2) always use "verbose" (-v).

Comment: The message tells you what to do. See the reference docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio's `Package Manager Console` with reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`, then you can execute the following command:

```
PM> Update-Database -context your_context -v
```

If you use `dotnet` command, then try this:

```
dotnet ef database update --context your_context
```